# Meaning of the Silence of the Lambs poster

Tags: the-silence-of-the-lambs, posters

I watched [**The Silence of the Lambs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_(film)) a couple of years ago. Yesterday I saw its poster online. It has a girl (which I am thinking is Clarice Starling, if I am not wrong) and a moth (or maybe a butterfly) on her mouth. I am just wondering, what does it mean? How is it related to the movie?

[image]

Comment: Beyond the obvious, you mean (that they find a moth's cocoon in a girl's mouth there)?

Comment: Indeed, beyond the moth being found in the murdered girl's mouth, and that moths / butterflies are a symbol of change, with Clarice developing as an agent, and the killer attempting to more literally change himself?

Comment: @iandotkelly Gave the OP the benefit of the doubt that they meant the *deeper* meaning, though, and posted my thoughts about it (and edited the Q).

Answer (score 87):

***This [award-winning](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/sin-city-place-be-at-139338) poster art conveys many of the movie's themes and plot points:***

- Clarice's skin is pale (in stark contrast to the darkness surrounding her) and blue like a corpse while her [blue eyes](http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fit,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,h_1200,q_80,w_1200/MTE4MDAzNDEwNTI0ODAwNTI2.jpg) had turned red, representing the film's themes of death, danger and virtue confronted with a malvolent influence (Lecter's eyes are red in the books, and another poster [featuring his face](http://www.impawards.com/1991/posters/silence_of_the_lambs_ver1_xlg.jpg) employed a similar color scheme).
- The moth with the skull pattern is a [death's-head hawkmoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s-head_hawkmoth) that's found in one of the bodies. Buffalo Bill inserts a moth's cocoon to the mouth of one of his female victims. Moths represent change in the movie, and other than explicitly representing *Buffalo Bill's* desire to change, it could certainly be argued that *Clarice* also transforms during the investigation.
- The [skull on the moth](http://posterwire.com/wp-content/themes/cruz/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://posterwire.com/wp-content/uploads/silence_of_the_lambs_slide.jpg&w=960&h=320) actually replicates [*In Voluptas Mors*](http://www.verbicidemagazine.com/2013/11/10/silence-of-the-lambs-skull-film-dali-photo/) **[Warning: Nudity]**, a photo conceived by Salvador Dali of *seven naked women*[*] that form a skull. This not only suggests the lewd nature of the crimes seen in the movie, which involve female bodies, but also the *complexity* involved (Lecter is an extremely cultured man and a skilled painter).
- The moth also covers Clarice's mouth to allude to that titular Silence [she so desperately needs](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47289/4386).

[*] *[As a point of interest: Before the plot starts in both book and movie, Buffalo Bill as a serial killer (since he's responsible for other, unrelated murders) had already kidnapped 5 women, skinned them and dumped their naked bodies in rivers. Later on, Starling would attend the autopsy of his 6th victim, and eventually save Catherine - **which would've been Bill's 7th victim**.]*

Comment: Man, movie posters used to be really good.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Indeed. The _In Voluptas Mors_ part reminds me of some of the [old Polish posters](https://www.buzzfeed.com/briangalindo/45-amazing-vintage-polish-posters-of-classic-american-films?utm_term=.am5OrmAx3#.bk0GmgOnw).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the real metamorphosis represented by the moth is Buffalo Bill's as he's trying to convert himself into a woman by building his suit of female skin.

Comment: [Congratulations, for the Rewards for best answer of 4th quarter of 2016](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/2562/1190)